# Skip authorization while unit testing in Lumen

Tags: middleware, lumen, lumen-5.8

Is there a way to skip Authorization middleware when running unit testing for a Lumen application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the test case add the following:

```
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;
...
```

When you run unit testing again the test case will run the application without the middleware.